# Get name of test method in setUp (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest

I want to append a message to a log that includes the name of the test method that is about to be run. I want to do this in my setUp method in my test superclass so I don't have repeated code everywhere.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
- (void) setUp {
    [super setUp];
    [self log:@NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}
```

However, _cmd always gives "setUp" as its string, whereas I want "test00TestTheThing"

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

I found this:

```
self.name
```

However, this gives me "-[AppUITests test00TestTheThing]"

Comment: Looks like that's what you want - it's a unique identifier for that test. If you only want the name of the test, you could use regex to extract it from the string you get, but I'd say having all the information is useful, even if it's just for navigating quickly to the test when you need to investigate it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it's still relevant but if someone needs it:

you can use the `self.name` and then you'll get the name of the class with the name of the test.

To remove the class name and just stay with the test name, use the `replacingOccurrences` func

example:

```
class ClassName: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
      // get the name and remove the class name and what comes before the class name
      var currentTestName = self.name.replacingOccurrences(of: "-[ClassName ", with: "")

      // And then you'll need to remove the closing square bracket at the end of the test name

      currentTestName = currentTestName.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
    }
```